# Access .data section in Position Independent Code

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, elf

I'm building a shared library with NASM. In that library, in some function, I need what we'd call a **static variable** in C. Basically, I think it is some space in the .data section:

```
    SECTION .data
last_tok:       dq 0 ; Define a QWORD
```

The problem arises when I try to **access** *last_tok* in my function.

I read the [NASM Manual: 8.2 Writing Linux/ELF Shared Libraries](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.f04/nasmdoc/html/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.2) which explains the problem and gives the solution.

```
    SECTION .data
last_tok:              dq 0     ; Define a QWORD

    SECTION .text
    EXTERN _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    GLOBAL strtok:function
strtok:
    enter    0, 0
    push     rbx
    call     .get_GOT
.get_GOT:
    pop      rbx
    add      rbx, _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ + $$ - .get_GOT wrt ..gotpc

    mov      [rbx + last_tok wrt ..gotoff], rdi ; Store the contents of RDI at last_tok

    mov      rbx, [rbp - 8]
    leave
    ret
```

It may work with ELF32, but with ELF64 I get the following error:

```
nasm -f elf64  -o strtok.o strtok.s
strtok:15: error: ELF64 requires ..gotoff references to be qword
<builtin>: recipe for target 'strtok.o' failed
make: *** [strtok.o] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The effective address format only allows for 32 bit displacement that is sign extended to 64 bit. According to the error message, you need full 64 bits. You can add it via a register, such as:

```
mov      rax,  last_tok wrt ..gotoff
mov      [rbx + rax], rdi
```

Also, the `call .get_GOT` is a 32 bit solution, in 64 bit mode you have rip relative addressing which you can use there. While the above may compile, but I am not sure it will work. Luckily the simple solution is to use the mentioned rip relative addressing to access your variable thus:

```
    SECTION .data
    GLOBAL last_tok
last_tok:              dq 0     ; Define a QWORD

    SECTION .text
    GLOBAL strtok:function
strtok:
    mov      rcx, [rel last_tok wrt ..gotpc]    ; load the address from the GOT
    mov      rax, [rcx]                         ; load the old dq value from there
    ; and/or
    mov      [rcx], rdi                         ; store arg at that address
    ret
```

Note that for a private (static) variable you can just use `[rel last_tok]` without having to mess with the got at all.

In a PIE executable, compilers use (the equivalent of) `[rel symbol]` to access even global variables, on the assumption that the main executable doesn't need or want symbol interposition for its own symbols.

(Symbol interposition, or symbols defined in other shared libraries, is the only reason to load symbol addresses from the GOT on x86-64.  But even something like `mov rdx, [rel stdin]` is safe in a PIE executable: https://godbolt.org/z/eTf87e - the linker creates a definition of the variable in the executable so it's within range and at a link-time-constant offset for RIP-relative addressing.)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about RIP-relative addressing in 64-bit mode. It makes things much more simple than in 32-bit mode! Also, I just read in the manual that the "rel" prefix is not even needed if "DEFAULT REL" is specified at the top of the file.

Comment: `[rel last_tok wrt ..gotpc]` holds the address of the *GOT entry*.  You need something like  `mov rax, [rel last_tok wrt ..gotpc]` / `mov [rax], rdi` to load that pointer from the GOT and dereference it.  You can only do this in 1 store instruction if you bypass the GOT (like for a `static` variable, or without symbol interposition) with `[rel last_tok]`.