# how to access glibc data types from an assembly program using got?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, got

I'm trying to access the `stdin` C FILE* type so i can call fgets to get input and echo it back. I can use plt section to access C functions but can't use `.got` section (which if i understand right is like plt but for data) in the same way for for `stdin` as a segmentation fault always result from `mov` instruction after `lea`

```
section .bss 
    BUFFERLEN equ 100
    BUFFER: resb BUFFERLEN
section .text
global main
extern stdin, fgets
main: 
default rel
    push rbp             
    mov rbp, rsp          
        ; First get input to print
    
    mov rdi, [rel BUFFER]
    mov rsi, BUFFERLEN
   
    mov rdx, [rel stdin wrt ..gotpc] 
    
    call fgets wrt ..plt
    
    pop rbp
    ret         ; return back to caller
```

built and linked with makefile as

```
proj13: proj13.o
    gcc -pie -fpie -o proj13 proj13.o
proj13.o: proj13.asm
    nasm -g -F DWARF -f elf64 -o proj13.o proj13.asm
```

Comment: Are you sure dereferencing is the right thing to do here...

Comment: off-topic, use `lea rdx, [rel BUFFER]` instead of a 64 bit absolute address, otherwise don't bother going through the GOT for libc symbols.  (Even for PIE executables, you don't have to, though.  Only to support symbol interposition for libraries, like `gcc -fPIC`.  https://godbolt.org/z/Kz1oEe shows the GAS `.intel_syntax` equivalent.)

Comment: @peterCordes yeah you are right didn't think of it. just wanted to make an example but does it have an effect on outcome ?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: yes, it is.  `FILE *stdin` is a pointer stored in static storage.  You do need to load a pointer from memory and pass it to `fgets`.  Not sure why this doesn't work, unless that's the wrong syntax.  In a debugger, it seems that `lea` puts `-40` into RCX with an absolute addressing mode.  Oh, perhaps that's the problem? 
 Missing `default rel`

Comment: @peterCordes the code above is exactly what i use without printing part gonna edit with build and assemble part

Comment: @peterCordes ```default rel``` seems to still cause segmentation fault, do you get different result. also edited question with build and link makefile if it can help

Comment: Yeah, I tried that on my machine.  It still puts an address very nearby into RCX, different from what GDB shows for `print &stdin` to show the symbol address, or `print (void*)stdin` to show the value.  Related: [Access .data section in Position Independent Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36223182) for going through the GOT to get to your own data, hopefully works unless `stdin` is special.  Probably `wrt ..got` is giving us the offset relative to the start of the GOT, not to the GOT entry from here.

Comment: Oh, `fgets()` takes the FILE* as the 3rd arg, in RDX not RDI.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html.  (Unlike `read()` with an fd.).  Wish I'd noticed that sooner, would have saved a bunch of debugging with NASM syntax for GOT-relative.

Comment: @peterCordes where in the man page does it link to which registers it takes it parameters since I still can't tell where to put BUFFER address.

Comment: All libc functions (and all compiler-generated functions) follow the x86-64 System V calling convention.  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989)

Comment: Wish there was some assembler shortcut for the ABI argument registers :D

Comment: @PeterCordes I still dont know why the error occures if ```rdi->BUFFET```, ```rsi->BUFFERLEN ``` ```rdx->stdin``` segmentation fault still occuer .

Comment: As in the linked duplicate, `mov rdx, [rel stdin]` works for me, and so does `mov   rdx, [rel stdin wrt ..gotpc]` / `mov rdx, [rdx]`.

Comment: That's *not* the same as my last comment.  You forgot the `mov rdx, [rdx]`.  In C terms, you're doing `fgets(..., &stdin)`, just loading its address from the GOT but not dereferencing.  (I updated the answer on the linked duplicate to show loading as well, as a reminder you need another load to dereference.) You really don't need to make it this complicated; also as described in [Access .data section in Position Independent Code](//stackoverflow.com/q/36223182), you can do `mov rdx, [rel stdin]` like compilers do in a PIE executable. You only need to go through the GOT for symbol interposition